Javascript get element where caret is in in a contenteditable
Let's say we have a contenteditable div, and inside the div there is a ul
<div contenteditable="true">
<ul>
<li>Some text here</li>
<li>Some more te|<- CARET HERExt</li>
</ul>
</div>

I need to get the node that the caret is inside, as well as the caret's index inside the innerText.
I have used the following code:
let selection = getSelection();
console.log(selection.focusNode);
console.log(selection.focusOffset);

Expected output:
<li>
12

Actual output:
<ul>
3


Under what event are you running your JS code?

@RoryMcCrossan ResizeObserver

user below code
    <div contenteditable="true">
        <ul onclick="getCaretDetails()">
        <li>Some text here</li>
        <li>Some more te|<- CARET HERExt</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
        function getCaretDetails() {
            let selection = getSelection();
            
            if (selection && selection.focusNode) {
                let focusNode = selection.focusNode;
                let focusOffset = selection.focusOffset;

                // Traverse up to find the text node if necessary
                while (focusNode && focusNode.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    focusNode = focusNode.childNodes[0];
                }

                if (focusNode && focusNode.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                    console.log('Node:', focusNode.parentNode); // Parent element of the text node
                    console.log('Index in text:', focusOffset);
                } else {
                    console.log('Caret is not within a text node.');
                }
            } else {
                console.log('No selection or focusNode is null.');
            }
        }



        </script>


Thank you @ram singh for your answer.
I adapted it slightly for my use - here is the code:
let selection = getSelection();
// console.log(selection);
let selection_focus_node, selection_focus_offset;
if (selection && selection.focusNode) {
    selection_focus_node = selection.focusNode;
    selection_focus_offset = selection.focusOffset;

    while (selection_focus_node.childNodes[0] && selection_focus_node.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        selection_focus_node = selection_focus_node.childNodes[0];
    }
}
else {
    console.log("No selection or focusNode is null");
}

